# Why Isnt My Condition Being Followed?

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-statements

```
$attributes = ['Strength_Item', 'Dexterity_Item', 'Intelligence_Item', 'Attacks_Per_Second_Percent', 'Crit_Damage_Percent',
   'Crit_Percent_Bonus_Capped', 'Hitpoints_Regen_Per_Second', 'Armor_Bonus_Item', 'Damage_Percent_Bonus_Vs_Elites'];

$cclass = 'wizard';

foreach($attributes as $i => $stat) {
   if($stat == 'Strength_Item' && ($cclass == 'crusader' || 'barbarian')){
      print($cclass);
      print($stat);
      $data += 270;
   }
}
```

Alright, so I have an if with the condition to only go if the $stat array is on the 'Strength_Item' portion and only if the $cclass is either 'crusader' or 'barbarian'. I set $cclass = 'wizard'.

However the if results as true, and it prints out 'wizardStrength_Item'. Meaning the cclass was indeed wizard. What am I doing wrong here that makes this disregard my second conditional?

Comment: Sidenote: Missing semi-colon for `$cclass = 'wizard'`

Comment: `$cclass == 'crusader' || 'barbarian'` --- doesn't do what you think. In programming you cannot do something that looks correct but must follow the syntax.

Comment: Use `($cclass == 'crusader' || $cclass == 'barbarian')`

Comment: or .. `in_array($cclass,array('crusader','barbarian'))` ..

Comment: Fred, thanks that was a typo on here only. The semi-colon is present in my code.

Comment: I had a feeling it was, just checking ;-)

Comment: Zerkms, thats exactly what Im asking this in the first place. Mike and Dagon, thank you for the help.

Comment: Zerkms Im sure youre perfect in every new thing you try. What doesnt make sense to me is when someone goes on a site intended to help people with such problems, you feel like you should say such things. I already got my answer and now I wont make the mistake again thanks to people that actually wanted to help.

Comment: Paul, @zerkms is a very helpful individual here, as is the case with anyone of 100K+ reputation. Unless a comment is particularly out of line, it's worth ignoring any perceived negativity, since assumptions of that kind are often wrong. More generally, it worth bearing in mind that everyone needs to a be a little bit bulletproof on Stack Overflow, so get your kevlar jacket on!

Comment: (I've rolled back your last minor edit, as we want questions to be written for posterity. Thus, chat and content not related to the topic at hand tends will tend to get edited out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
foreach($attributes as $stat) {
   if($stat == 'Strength_Item' && ($cclass == 'crusader' || $cclass == 'barbarian')){
      print($cclass);
      print($stat);
      $data += 270;
   }
}
```